# Difference between double and single square brackets in regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

Why is it that in R when using a single square brackets here returns FALSE, whereas using double square brackets returns TRUE? Example:

```
> grepl('[:alpha:]', 'AA')
[1] FALSE
> grepl('[[:alpha:]]', 'AA')
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `[:alpha:]` A posix character class may only appear inside a character class.

Comment: `[:alpha:]` only works in ICU regex, with `stringr` functions. Basically, in almost all flavors supporting POSIX character classes, the POSIX character classes must be used inside bracket expressions.

Answer (score -1):

[[:alpha:]] is a specific character class unique to regex in R. Check out character classes here

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: The mere fact they are called *POSIX* character classes implies they are not unique to R regex. And you may use `[:alpha:]`, too, but with `stringr` functions that are powered with the ICU regex library.